# No print message from socket server, reciving response from client sent message

Tags: python, sockets, python-multithreading

I am setting up a client/server in Python with the ability to handle multiple clients.

Server code:

```
import socket
import threading

class Server:
    def __init__(self):
        self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server.bind(('127.0.0.1',1234 ))
        print("Waiting for connection")
        self.server.listen()

        self.loop()

    def thread_client(self, conn, addr):
        print(addr, ' has connected')
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            conn.sendall(data)

    def loop(self):
        while True:
            conn, addr = self.server.accept()
            x = threading.Thread(target = self.thread_client, args=(conn, addr,))
            x.start()
        self.server.close()

s = Server()
```

Client code:

```
import socket

class Client:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.connect()
    
    def connect(self):
        try:
            self.client.connect(('127.0.0.1', 1234))
        except:
            print("Something went wrong...")

    def send(self, data):
        self.client.sendall(data)
        return self.client.recv(1024)

c = Client()
print(c.send(b'Hello World'))
print(c.send(b'Hello World'))
```

When I run `py server.py` in one terminal this is all I get:
[image]

And from the client terminal this is how it looks:
[image]

My question is, why am I not recieving a simple print message from the initialization of the server? What does CLOSE_WAIT and FIN_WAIT_2 mean when I run netstat?

Comment: If I remove ```self.loop()``` from the server initialization is does print out the message.

Comment: Try closing the connection on both the client and server when each is done.

Answer (score 0):

The server thread will loop forever until the socket times out resulting in WAIT states on the created sockets as shown in netstat command. Add a check in the server thread to check when data from the client is complete.

[Socket Programming HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html) states:

> When a socket.recv returns 0 bytes, it means the other side has closed
> (or is in the process of closing) the connection. You will not receive any
> more data on this connection.

**Server update:**

```python
import socket
import threading

class Server:
    def __init__(self):
        self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server.bind(('127.0.0.1', 1234))
        print("Waiting for connection")
        self.server.listen()

        self.loop()

    def loop(self):
        while True:
            conn, addr = self.server.accept()
            x = threading.Thread(target=Server.thread_client, args=(conn, addr,))
            x.start()
        self.server.close()

    @staticmethod
    def thread_client(conn, addr):
        print(addr, ' has connected')
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            if len(data) == 0:
                break
            print("recv:", data)
            conn.sendall(data)
        conn.close()

s = Server()
```

For the client, close the socket connect when done.

**Client update:**

```
c = Client()
print(c.send(b'Hello World'))
print(c.send(b'Hello World'))
c.client.close()  # added
```